# How can i overwrite file when use move action whether file exist same name in alfresco?

Tags: alfresco

I moved file to another folder if file exist with that name it 's raise error "file already exist". How can i overwrite it to the exist one using move action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example of same whatever you want to achive but different way.
Might be you will get some idea from that.
https://github.com/keensoft/alfresco-version-by-name